# Catalog Price Rule Grid Is Missing Columns

Tags: magento2, grid, catalog-price-rules

According to the official docs of Magento 2.4* https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html Catalog Price Rule should have the option to filter by '**Status**', '**start**' and so on. Instead those columns are missing.

How can I extend the current grid with those columns?

**Expected behavior:**
[image]

**Current behavior:**
[image]

What have i tried so far:

- Found out that under **src/vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_rule_promo_catalog_block.xml** the wanted column is indeed added. I cound't find any di.xml which overwrites the column class

  ```
                   <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="promo.catalog.grid.columnSet.is_active" as="is_active">
                   <arguments>
                       <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                       <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">is_active</argument>
                       <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                       <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                           <item name="active" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                           </item>
                           <item name="inactive" xsi:type="array">
                               <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                               <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Inactive</item>
                           </item>
                       </argument>
                   </arguments>
               </block>
  ```
- Also I´ve installed a naked Magento 2 instance same behavior...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento Commerce  (EE edition) uses Staging functionality to define the date when rules will be applied, it's why date from/date to fields was removed from  different entities/grids like catalog price rules, special prices, etc

Comment: Thank you I`ve overwrited the module: CatalogSalesRuleStaging layout.xml and it worked as intended.

Answer (score 0):

`catalog_rule_promo_catalog_block.xml` is overridden by `vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule-staging/view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_rule_promo_catalog_block.xml` in EE edition.

You can add a column in your own module, for instance, the status column. Do not forget to reference the Magento_CatalogRuleStaging module in your module.

Create the file /view/adminhtml/layout/catalog_rule_promo_catalog_block.xml in your module and reference the column grid block, and add the status field:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="promo.catalog.grid.columnSet">
                <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" name="promo.catalog.grid.columnSet.is_active" as="is_active">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</argument>
                        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">is_active</argument>
                        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
                        <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="active" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Active</item>
                            </item>
                            <item name="inactive" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Inactive</item>
                            </item>
                        </argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Thats exactly how ive overwrited the block as well thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to upvote your answer